# Gtk-WARNING when running Gedit in WSL

Tags: gtk, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gedit

I am getting this error whenever I try to open Gedit on WSL on Ubuntu terminal:

```
(gedit:3271): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:10:01.110: cannot open display:
```

Please suggest a fix to it.
Thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu in WSL is by default CLI only so the error message is correct because there is no display. Not an error, it's exactly how it should be.

Comment: So, how can i use gedit in wsl linux?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use gedit?

Comment: Then in which editor do I type my c program and stuff?

Comment: @RamitBose21BCE1316 You are probably just running on a slightly outdated WSL release.  WSL now supports the ability to run GUI applications for both Windows 10 and 11, but you'll need to upgrade first.  If you've already upgraded, though, let me know and we'll look for other causes.  As for "which editor", the typical recommendation on WSL is to use the *Windows* version of Visual Studio Code, with the [WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=m).  This will fully integrate the Windows VSCode with WSL.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Just for clarity/update, WSL *by default* now has GUI support.  It's likely the OP just hasn't updated to the latest Windows/WSL release, but it's available for all users now.

Comment: @RamitBose21BCE1316 One final note, though - If you are going to be editing C code, I highly recommend that you get used to the `vi` key bindings anyway.  You can run `vi` (or Neovim) directly from the terminal without requiring any overhead of a graphical application.  But even when using VSCode, I recommend the `vi` keybindings -- Once you invest the time in learning them, it will make editing so much faster in the future.